# Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap#0'

Tags: spring-saml

I am adding SSO code in the webpage using SAML. And for this process I added the following code for Maven.

```
        <!-- Spring Framework Security -->
            <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
          <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-config -->
       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.2.RELEASE</version>
       </dependency>    


        <!-- Spring Security SAML -->
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework.security.extensions</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring-security-saml2-core</artifactId>
          <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

And I added the following code in the application context xml.

```
  <!-- Initialization of OpenSAML library -->
  <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap" />
```

But I get the following error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name
>   'org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap#0' defined in class
>   path resource [conf/spring/root-context.xml]: Instantiation of bean
>   failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [org.springframework.security.saml.SAMLBootstrap]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/springframework/beans/factory/access/BootstrapException

It appears certain jars are missing. How do I add this jar?

Thanks
Jae Kim

Answer (score 2):

**Bottom line is: update to 1.0.3.RELEASE solves the problem.**

**Explanation**: class `SAMLBootstrap` throws (line 45) `BootstrapException`, which exists in spring-4 (spring-beans-4.2.4.RELEASE)  but not in spring-5.

In spring-security-saml2-core-1.0.3.RELEASE the dependency in class `BootstrapException` is removed.

Answer (score 1):

According to this issue https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-saml/issues/211

You just have to update saml library to the latest version

1.0.4.RELEASE

Comment: I tried 1.0.4.RELEASE but it caused other problems.
I read through that article and it says 1.0.3.RELEASE.
Using 1.0.3.RELEASE solved the problem.